# c# Dot Net Browser Error | BrowserException was unhandled by user code |

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I was trying to use Chrome browser in c# by using Dot Net Browser, However I was getting this error on both Windows Form And WPF c# Applications, I would be so thankful if anyone can help me to solve it.

A picture(s) from the error:

http://uupload.ir/files/xr7a_bandicam_2016-10-08_17-42-15-245.jpg
http://uupload.ir/files/3v5f_bandicam_2016-10-08_18-02-04-040.jpg

Comment: It says right in the error: "License evaluation period has expired"

Comment: Lol thank you didn't notice it just now.